# How to determine if an array of string objects is empty using ngIf?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, underscore.js

I have to write a code in which I must transfer some items between two lists and hide an error when the array of object literals to be transferred to isn't empty. I have created two controllers(to manage two separate lists) and one service to deal with common data. A list has been defined inside the service along with some functions to transfer items from one list to another. The array size never seemed to change from 0,which is the logic i am trying to use in ngIf.

My logic was to check if the array is empty, then return a value of true if it was empty and set a variable empty in the controller. Then in ng-if I will check ng-if="b.empty" and thought that that would work but it didnt. The array size would remain 0 all throughout the life cycle of my code. I used ._isEmpty(list),angular([],[]) and the most obvious, array.length but the issue was initially they showed 0, but then the array size never changed. Even after populating the target array, the size seemed to stay 0 with any/all of the above functions/methods.

```
l1.$inject = ['listService']
function l1(listService){
    var buying = this;
    buying.items = listService.display();
    buying.Add = function ($index){
        listService.addItem($index);
    }
};    //This is the controller for the source array.
.
.
.
bought.empty = listService.checkIfFull();   //Part of the second controller which assigns empty a boolean value
.
.
.
service.checkIfFull = function (){
    if(blist.length == 0){
        console.log(_.isEmpty(blist))
        console.log(tblist)
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("not going here");
        return true;
    }
};    //The service checks if the array is empty
```

```
<div class="emptyMessage" ng-if="b.empty">Nothing bought</div>
```

The value of the console.log statements also only seem to be executing in the true portion of the if statement. I found a solution for this, which was to simply check in the html tag itself, if the local list's(that I'm looping through which ng-repeat)length was equal to zero and that worked. But could you please explain why my attempt is wrong? I am a beginner to AngularJs and JS in general so i might have not understood some rules about js and thus written wrong code. Thank you.

Edit: Here's the link to the codepen-> https://codepen.io/meanmanmachineman/pen/RmmdjY

Comment: It's not an array of object *literals*. It's an array of *objects*. An object *literal* is a syntax thing, such as the `{} `in `var o = {};` The runtime thing is an object.

Comment: `ng-if="!b || b.length === 0"`

Comment: Are you sure that you are working with arrays? Some backends will encode PHP arrays as JavaScript objects. JavaScript objects will not change their `.length` property even when using integers in accessor square brackets.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am using an array of object literals. My array goes as
    var array = [ { name: "", quantity: ""},{ ...}... ]

Comment: @georgeawg definitely sure, there are no PHP scripts running anywhere so there's no possibility of that happening.

Comment: @need_to_know_now - Right. So you're working with an array of objects whose property values are strings, not an array literal of object literals whose property values are string literals. Syntax vs the actual thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh alright, thanks for clearing that up. I interpreted the nomenclature wrongly.

Comment: @need_to_know_now - It's just useful when searching, etc. :-) Can you update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem? Ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is the most i can explain the question without being overly verbose. The code snippet i have added it the perfect amount i feel to be understood by a reader/expert. I'll ad a jsfiddle link, would that be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the line `bought.empty = listService.checkIfFull();`. There you are calling to the function `listService.checkIfFull()` and assigning the returned value to `bought.empty`. What you should do is to assign the function itself to `bought.empty`:

```
bought.empty = listService.checkIfFull;
```

This way each time `bought.empty` is evaluated, it returns the current real value.

EDIT:

I'll try to be more explicit about the difference between, `bought.empty = listService.checkIfFull()` and `bought.empty = listService.checkIfFull`.

The first way, `bought.empty` will call to `listService.checkIfFull()` and store the returned value as a static value and any time the variable is evaluated, the value will be the same.

By using the other method, the value of `bought.empty` is not a number but the `listService.checkIfFull` function itself. This way, each time AngularJS evaluates the variable, the function is executed and returns the corresponding value.

Comment: I come from a background of C++/Java where assigning a function to a value is the same as setting the return value of that function as the value for the variable. I do not understand what the difference is between     bought.empty = listService.checkIfFull() and     bought.empty = checkIfFull. Could you please clarify what is going on in each of them some more?

Comment: I have edited my answer to try to explain the difference between the two methods. I hope I did it right

Comment: Oh so is this feature limited to Javascript? Because in C/C++ there's only one way to do the same thing so i assumed that writing it in the var = function() form would automatically mean that variable was getting updated each time.
Also, i just executed this in my codepen, but its still not working correctly. Maybe something is wrong in my ng-if?

Comment: I have never coded in C or C++ but in JavaScript it works this way. Try the code and let me know if everything works correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized I was missing something else to say about your code. As you assign the function to the variable, so that `bought.empty` is effectively a function (since its value is a function) you must refer to it as a function from the HTML code: `<div class="emptyMessage" ng-if="b.empty()">Nothing bought</div>`

Comment: Yes this works. Although your explanation for it confuses me(its a function because its value is a function), i do not think that it is your fault. I think it's something to do with my coding background. it never works this way in C/C++/Java. Thank you for the help, ill look up on this topic some more as i feel that this is an important juncture in JS.